# First canvas goes blank when 2nd canvas is created

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to load two different Pokemon for battle.
First, it chooses a random Pokemon to fight and displays its canvas window with its hp life bar inside.
Then Second, you choose your Pokemon, When that happens it loads the 2nd canvas causing the first canvas to go blank.
I have tried everything to resolve this even with chatGBT and still got nothing.
I don't know why the first canvas goes blank. And on top of that when you click on the canvas windows they say not responding.
The Enemies Life Bar Module is the same code as the LifeBar Module(Your Pokemon HP Module)
So you have LifeBar Module
And you have EnemiesLifeBar Module

Enemies Life Bar Module

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class EnemiesLifeBar:
    def __init__(self, name, max_life, current_life):
        self.image_path = ""
        self.pokemon_photo = ""
        self.pokemon_image = ""
        self.name = name
        self.max_life = max_life
        self.current_life = current_life
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title(name)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=300, height=30, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.damage_taken = 0
        self.damage_taken_done = 0
        self.damage_increase = 0
        self.damage_increase_done = 0

        if self.damage_taken_done == 1:
            self.root.after(30, self.animate_damage_taken)
        if self.damage_increase_done == 1:
            self.root.after(30, self.animate_health_increase)

        # Load Pokémon image
        self.image_path = "C:/Users/Samuel~1/Desktop/PokeMonSounds/Images/" + name + ".png"
        self.pokemon_image = Image.open(self.image_path)
        self.pokemon_image = self.pokemon_image.resize((100, 100))
        self.pokemon_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pokemon_image)
        self.pokemon_label = tk.Label(self.root, image=self.pokemon_photo)
        self.pokemon_label.pack()  # Adjust as needed

        # Display life bar
        self.update_life_bar()

    def update_life_bar(self):
        bar_width = (self.current_life / self.max_life) * 300
        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, bar_width, 30, fill='red')
        self.canvas.create_text(150, 15, text=f"Life: {self.current_life}/{self.max_life}", fill='white')
        self.root.update()

    def decrease_life(self, amount):
        self.current_life -= amount
        if self.current_life < 0:
            self.current_life = 0
        self.update_life_bar()

    def increase_life(self, amount):
        self.current_life += amount
        if self.current_life > 100:
            self.current_life = 100
        self.update_life_bar()

    def animate_damage_taken(self):
        if self.damage_taken > 0:
            self.decrease_life(1)
            self.root.after(30, self.animate_damage_taken)
            self.damage_taken -= 1

    def animate_health_increase(self):
        if self.damage_increase > 0:
            self.increase_life(1)
            self.root.after(30, self.animate_health_increase)
            self.damage_increase -= 1

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
        self.run()
```

Comment: A shot in the dark but try changing `ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pokemon_image)` to `ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pokemon_image, master=self.root)`. Also show us the code that creates and uses the `EnemiesLifeBar` class (you need to keep a reference to all of your `EnemiesLifeBar` objects).